# How to draw a grid of node points with labels above

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am looking to make something similar to this, does anyone know how I could go about this? Quite new to TEX so apologies if it is quite trivial.

[image: Labeled gird points]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have some code to start with? It would help us help you if we knew, for example, which packages you'd like to use. If you really don't know how to start, you could take a look around on this side to find some more or less suitable example code at least.

Comment: This is just a table without border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

I'd do this as an exercise of conditionals and loops. With the help of the `ifthen` package you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\i in {0,...,4} \foreach\j in {-1,...,5}
{
  \ifthenelse{\i=0 \OR \i=4}{\def\l{C}}{\def\l{u}}                        % letter
  \ifthenelse{\i=0 \OR \i=4 \OR \j=-1 \OR \j=5}{\def\s{*}}{\def\s{\circ}} % symbol
  \pgfmathparse{int(\i*\i*(\i-4)*(\i-4)+(\j+1)*(\j+1)*(\j-5)*(\j-5))}
  \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult>0}
  {%
    \node at (\i,\j) {$\l_{\i,\j}$};
    \node at (\i,\j-0.5) {$\s$};
  }{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No special packages are needed for this table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{ccccc}
        & u_{1,5}  & u_{2,5}  & u_{3,5}  & \\
        & \ast     & \ast     & \ast     & \\
C_{0,4} & u_{1,4}  & u_{2,4}  & u_{3,4}  & C_{4,4} \\
\ast    & \circ    & \circ    & \circ    & \ast \\
C_{0,3} & u_{1,3}  & u_{2,3}  & u_{3,3}  & C_{4,3} \\
\ast    & \circ    & \circ    & \circ    & \ast \\
C_{0,2} & u_{1,2}  & u_{2,2}  & u_{3,2}  & C_{4,2} \\
\ast    & \circ    & \circ    & \circ    & \ast \\
C_{0,1} & u_{1,1}  & u_{2,1}  & u_{3,1}  & C_{4,1} \\
\ast    & \circ    & \circ    & \circ    & \ast \\
C_{0,0} & u_{1,0}  & u_{2,0}  & u_{3,0}  & C_{4,0} \\
\ast    & \circ    & \circ    & \circ    & \ast \\
        & u_{1,-1} & u_{2,-1} & u_{3,-1} & \\
        & \ast     & \ast     & \ast     & \\
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Compiling with plain `pdflatex` produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `matrix of nodes` (I only put the first two rows as example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes] {
          & u_{1,5} & u_{2,5} & u_{3,5} &         \\
          & \ast    & \ast    & \ast    &         \\
  C_{0,4} & u_{1,4} & u_{2,4} & u_{3,4} & C_{4,4} \\
  \ast    & \circ   & \circ   & \circ   & \ast    \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, this is actually just a table and you may not necessarily need to do this with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % for simpler typing: create a column type that prepends and appends dollar signs for math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CCCCC}
          & u_{1,5} & u_{2,5} & u_{3,5} &         \\
          & \ast    & \ast    & \ast    &         \\
  C_{0,4} & u_{1,4} & u_{2,4} & u_{3,4} & C_{4,4} \\
  \ast    & \circ   & \circ   & \circ   & \ast    
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Surely it's simplest just to use an `array` environment?

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I still thought it would be nice to give some alternatives.